# What does hive do behind the scenes when I load the data?

Tags: database, facebook, hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming

I know that hive saves data as partiotions into the hadoop file system. However, how does the exact process work when I do `LOAD DATA` in hive?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that hive saves data as partiotions into the hadoop file system.

Hive doesn't store the data. Hive can be thought as a higher level abstract on top of the MapReduce computing model.

Assuming that the data is already there in HDFS and the table is created in Hive, the `LOAD DATA` command will just map the data in HDFS to the table created in Hive. The mapping is stored in the Hive metastore database, which is derby by default. [Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/11/differentWaysOfConfiguringHiveMetastore.html) is an article about  the types of Hive metastore and how to configure them.

It's a matter of just inserting/updating a couple of rows in the metastore database, which is the reason why the `LOAD DATA` command is fast.